# Помогите поправить работу кода PHP

Tags: php, php7

Доброго времени суток.
У меня есть задача ( уровень наверное школа - техникум, что то вроде того).
Заключается в следующем.
В **$_POST["FatalErrors"]** и **$_POST["Warnings"]** пользователь задаёт 2 числа, которые должны обработаться так:
Если из F вычитается 1, то прибавляется 1 к F
Если из W вычитается 1, то прибавляется 2 к W
Если из W вычитается 2, то прибавляется 1 к F
Если из F вычитается 2, то ничего не происходит, просто вычитается эти 2.

То есть алгоритм в итоге должен либо сделать числа равными нулю и показать количество итераций, либо выдать невозможность приведения к нулю этих чисел.

Я имею следующий код:

```
$FatalErrors = $_POST["FatalErrors"];
$Warnings = $_POST["Warnings"];


$i = 0;


    while($FatalErrors != 0 OR $Warnings != 0){

        if ($FatalErrors >= 2) {
            $FatalErrors -= 2;
            $i++;
        };

        if ($Warnings >= 2){
             $Warnings -= 2;
             $FatalErrors += 1;
             $i++;
        };

        if ($Warnings == 1) {
            $Warnings += 1;
            $i++;
        };
        
        
        if ($FatalErrors == 1 && $Warnings == 0 ){
            
         echo ("-1");
         break;
        }
            
                   
    };


    echo "<br>";
echo $i;

    echo "<br>";


echo $FatalErrors . "итог F(N)";
echo $Warnings . "итог W(M)";
```

И вроде как всё работает, НО есть числа, которые должны работать с задачей, а у меня не работают, в пример мне дали *F = 987 W = 100*, в итоге должно выдать нули и число итераций в виде 572, так как это решабельная вариация чисел, а вот мой код пишет - **"Невозможно"**, да и просто числа *F = 3 W = 3* должно тоже решаться с 9 итераций, но я видимо что-то упускаю.
Как это решить - так и не понял, может кто-то подскажет или не замыленным взглядом, видна какая то ошибка относительно задачи, а я просто её пропускаю.

Заранее спасибо.

P/S
Собственно само задание
*У программиста есть код на PHP. У него было N фатальных ошибок и M
ворнингов. Он решил заставить код работать без ошибок и ворнингов. Он не очень опытный
разработчик.   Если он исправляет одну фатальную ошибку за коммит, то вместо неё
появляется одна новая, если исправляет ворнинг в коммите, то вместо него
появляется два новых ворнинга.   Если он исправляет два ворнинга за один коммит,
то появляется одна новая фатальная ошибка, и только когда он исправляет сразу
две фатальные ошибки за один коммит, то не появляется ничего нового. Он считает,
что код будет полностью рабочим только если исправить все фатальные ошибки и
ворнинги.

Определи минимальное количество коммитов, нужное для исправления всех багов.
Напиши php-скрипт, который определит минимальное количество коммитов,
необходимых для исправления кода.

Входные данные

В форму на странице можно ввести два числа N, M (0 ≤ N, M ≤ 1000).

Выходные данные

Нужно вывести одно число – минимальное количество коммитов, или -1, если
исправить код Пети невозможно.

Пример входных данных:

3 3

Пример выходных данных:

9*

Comment: Напишите текст задачи оригинальный. В вашем варианте задачи из W никогда ничего не вычитается.

Comment: @Максим Степанов Добавил.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я не знаю насчет оптимальности, но мне в голову пока пришел такой алгоритм:

1. Уничтожить все варнинги так, чтобы фатальных осталось четное число.
2. Уничтожить все фатальные по 2.

Вообще, возможно я не до конца понимаю условие. При такой постановке задачи любая комбинация ошибок будет решаемая. Ведь варнингами можно подстроить и количество варнингов, и количество фатальных.

Вот такой получился код:

```php
<?php

$f = 987; $w = 100; $i = 0;

// шаг 1: приведем количество варнингов к четному числу
if ($w % 2 !== 0) {
    fix('w', 1, $f, $w, $i);
}

// шаг 2: если сумма фатальных ошибок и половины варнингов нечетная, добавим два варнинга:
// то есть сделаем так, чтобы после уничтожения всех варнингов число фатальных ошибок было четное
if ((($w / 2) + $f) % 2 !== 0) {
    fix('w', 1, $f, $w, $i);
    fix('w', 1, $f, $w, $i);
}

// шаu 3: уничтожаем все варнинги:
while ($w > 0) {
    fix('w', 2, $f, $w, $i);
}

// шаг 4 уничтожаем все фатальные ошибки.
while ($f > 0) {
    fix('f', 2, $f, $w, $i);
}

echo '<p>i: ' . $i . ', F: ' . $f . ', W: ' . $w . '</p>';


// вывод:

// $f = 3; $w = 3; $i = 0;
// i: 9, F: 0, W: 0

// $f = 987; $w = 100; $i = 0;
// i: 572, F: 0, W: 0


function fix($type, $count, &$f, &$w, &$i)
{
    $i++;
    
    switch ($type . $count) {
        case 'f1':
            break;
        case 'f2':
            $f -= 2;
            break;
        case 'w1':
            $w += 1;
            break;
        case 'w2':
            $w -= 2;
            $f += 1;
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Забавно, но весь подвох был в том, что решение ваше - верное, то есть нет вариаций не решаемых. Правда я сделал другой код, но с тем-же функционалом, без ООП.   
Спасибо

Comment: Не за что, тут правда ООП никакого нет, ну да не суть.

Comment: Ох, ну да, я просто увидел функцию и почему-то в голове сложилось впечатление, что это ООП, не могу сказать почему) просто я взял ваш метод за основу, но сделал иначе. Спасибо ещё раз!

Answer (score 1):

Так ?

```
$FatalErrors = 3;
 $Warnings = 3;
 $i = 0;
    while(true)
    {
        if ($FatalErrors >= 2) $FatalErrors -= 2;
        elseif ($FatalErrors == 1) $FatalErrors +=1;
        if ($Warnings >= 2) $Warnings -= 2;
        elseif ($Warnings == 1) $Warnings += 1;
        
        if ($FatalErrors == 0 && $Warnings == 0 ){
         echo ("Возможно. Число итераций - ".$i);
         break;
        }
       $i++;
                   
    }
```

Comment: не совсем, вы добавили строку, где   ` if ($FatalErrors == 1) $FatalErrors +=1;`
а я так понимаю из задания, что удаление одной FatalErrors не возможно, то есть если остаётся 1 FatalErrors и 0 Warnings - то задача не решается. То есть при FatalErrors = 1 никаких действий с FatalErrors производить не нужно.

Comment: @АндрейМисайлов Так у Вас условие - Если из F вычитается 1, то прибавляется 1 к F. Либо уточняйте её у преподавателя, либо формулируйте правильное задание. По текущему заданию - условия выполняются и числа 3 и 3, 987 и 100 и т.п. являются решаемыми. Если Вам нужно строго, что когда `$f = 1`, а `$warn = 0`, то добавьте условие. Хотя согласно Вашему заданию - такого просто не может быть т.к. опять же смотрим условие, когда `$f=$f+1`

Comment: @АндрейМисайлов Еще, когда считаете итерации, не обязательно пихать их в каждое условие. Значение будет неверное. Круг прошел - тогда прибавляете. А по факту Вы прибавляете 1 к итерации каждый раз, когда выполняется условие. Добавил в пример вывод итераций.

Comment: @sousage2012 итерации у меня как раз будут вернее, если я правильно понял задание, так как с числами 3 и 3 должно получиться 9 итераций, а с числами 987 и 100 - 572. У вас же числа 3 и 3 выдали 2 итерации а вторые 494
P/S мне ответил препод, что сама логика работы у меня в решении - не верная.

Comment: Кроме того тут видно, что если 1 Warning, то мы отнимаем 1 и прибавляем 2, так, что в случае с 1 FatalErrors я думаю та-же система.

Comment: @АндрейМисайлов У Вас неправильно понимание слова "Итерация". То, что сделали вы - не является итерацией. Итерация это повторение мат. операции. В данном случае - цикла. Вы же просто считаете, сколько раз выполнилось условие, но не за сколько итераций выполнилась задача. И как у Вас с 3 и 3 получается 9 итераций, когда даже при подсчете на пальцах там получается 2 итерации ?

Comment: @АндрейМисайлов для понимания, подставьте 3 и 3 в цикл. 3 больше 2 ? Да. Отнимаем 2. Остается 1. 1 == 1? Да. Прибавляем 1 и получается 2. Первая итерация закончена. На второй опять проверка 2 >= 2 ? Да. Отнимаем 2. Все.

Comment: @АндрейМисайлов Вы преподу мою логику показывали ? У Вас то понятное дело, что неверная. Вы же поэтому просите помощи. Мою покажите и спросите. Если неверная, то пусть задачу корректней распишет т.к. в задаче у Вас одно, а в решении совсем другое.

Comment: Может быть будет хоть как-то понятно, если я напишу саму задачу? А не то, как я её интерпретировал, может я просто не так доношу её и по этому все вопросы...

Comment: @АндрейМисайлов Попробуйте, вдруг что-то прояснится

Comment: добавил в описание саму задачу.

Comment: @АндрейМисайлов лично у меня не получается из 3 и 3 получить нули за 9 итераций..либо в задаче не хватает условия, либо я что то неправильно делаю. Может другие подскажут. В моем случае остается `fatal =1; warn = 0;`, а при 987 и 100 у меня получается максимум 542 итерации и меньше

Comment: Весь прикол в том, что у меня получается тоже самое) Надо докапываться до преподавателя. Если получу решение - напишу тут, тогда